# Consumer / producer does not wait for event

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore, python-2.x

I want write a program producer/consumer, in this program I have a parent and a son, the parent fills a shared variable with a number of fish and it send notify at son.
The son start eating, if there are not fish, it notify parent.
I tried this code, but it not working:

```
import threading
import time

NUM_FISH = 13

mutex = threading.Lock()
mutParent = threading.Event()
mutSon = threading.Event()

fish = NUM_FISH

def set(fish1):
    global fish
    fish = fish1

def get():
    return fish

def parent(mutParent, mutSon):
    while True:
                mutex.acquire()
                mutParent.wait()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                try:
                    set(NUM_FISH)
                    print " + parent brings %d fish\n" % fish             
                    mutex.release()
                    mutSon.set()
                except:
                    print "Exception"
                    mutex.release()

def son(id, mutParent, mutSon):
    while True:
                mutex.acquire()
                mutSon.wait()
                fish = get() - 1
                set(fish)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                try:
                    if fish > 0 :
                        print " - Son %d eats (dish: %d fish)\n" % (id, fish)
                        mutex.release()
                    else:
                        print " - Son %d eats (dish: %d fish) and screams\n\n" % (id, fish)
                        mutex.release()
                        mutParent.set()
                except:
                    print "Exception"
                    mutex.release()

print "\n + intitial dish: %d fish\n\n" % fish

mutSon.set()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=son, args=(1, mutParent, mutSon))
t2.start()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=parent, args = (mutParent, mutSon))
t1.start()

t2.join()
t1.join()
```

This is my output:

```
myself@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python a.py

 + intitial dish: 13 fish


 - Son 1 eats (dish: 12 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 11 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 10 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 9 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 8 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 7 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 6 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 5 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 4 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 3 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 2 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 1 fish)

 - Son 1 eats (dish: 0 fish) and screams


 - Son 1 eats (dish: -1 fish) and screams


 - Son 1 eats (dish: -2 fish) and screams


 - Son 1 eats (dish: -3 fish) and screams


 - Son 1 eats (dish: -4 fish) and screams


 - Son 1 eats (dish: -5 fish) and screams


 + parent brings 13 fish

 + parent brings 13 fish
```

Comment: Sorry, Arch Linux x86 32 bit, for me not working always

Comment: You never `clear` either of your `Event`s, and thus, neither thread ever has to actually wait for their event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, there are three things here that can be changed:

1. This one is sort of cosmetic. Use `with mutex:` instead of all the `mutex.acquire()` and `mutex.release()`, as then that stuff happens automatically, making the code shorter and less error prone.
2. You should wait for your events before acquiring `mutex`. Otherwise a thread will acquire the mutex, then begin to wait for its condition variable, however, the tread that is supposed to set it can't acquire `mutex`, so everything stops. Note that, when there is multiple sons or parents, the event has to be rechecked after locking `mutex`. This is because after waiting for the event, the event may be cleared before `mutex` has been acquired.
3. After waiting for an event, you should act on the event, then clear it. Otherwise, when the son thread sets the event, the parent wakes up and deals with it. However, as the event is still set, if the parent wakes up again, it proceeds again, giving the double parent lines (and double son sections).

Making those adjustments gives me this code:

```
def parent(id, mutParent, mutSon):
    while True:
        mutParent.wait()
        with mutex:
            if not mutParent.is_set():
                continue
            time.sleep(0.5)
            try:
                set(NUM_FISH)
                print " + Parent %d brings %d fish\n" % (id, fish)
                mutParent.clear()
                mutSon.set()
            except:
                print "Exception"

def son(id, mutParent, mutSon):
    while True:
        mutSon.wait()
        with mutex:
            if not mutSon.is_set():
                continue
            fish = get() - 1
            set(fish)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            try:
                if fish > 0:
                    print " - Son %d eats (dish: %d fish)\n" % (id, fish)
                else:
                    print " - Son %d eats (dish: %d fish) and screams\n\n" % (id, fish)
                    mutSon.clear()
                    mutParent.set()
            except:
                print "Exception"
```

I haven't managed to break this (works with multiple sons or parents), so I think its correct, but any correction on this point is most welcome (as this is multithreading, and weird things lie in the shadows of parallelism).

Comment: try with multiple consumer (son) threads.  You still have an error that you'll get negative fish with multiple consumers.

Comment: In fact, through testing, if you have `n` consumers, you'll end up with a `dish` with (a possible) `1 - n` fish on it at its low point.  The subtraction needs to happen *after* you make sure there's still a fish on the dish.

Comment: I've found the bug, its that once an event has been waited for, it may be unset before the mutex is locked. I'll update the answer.